# Export to EXCEL from SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services using command line

Tags: command-line, export-to-excel, sql-server-2017, sqlreportingservice

Using command line to export report from SQL Server Reporting Services (RDL) to Excel format.

I tried using the `RS.exe` utility - but it's not working with RDL files. I have a report on SQL Server 2017 Reporting Services; when exporting to Excel using the button on the page, all is working fine.

I am trying to create a script that will export this report every 3 hours.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why don't you setup a subscription for that frequency?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on creating a subscription i am not familiar with the subject.

Comment: Go to SSRS report page and click on the `...` for that report, then click `Subscribe`, fill out the information and save.

Comment: Thanks - it is working - not exactly what i wanted works - how do i mark as answer?

Comment: I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a subscription for the report and set the frequency to your needs.

Go to SSRS report page and click on the `...` for that report, then click `Subscribe`, fill out the information and save.